# Do Apex rest services methods like @HttpPost support Apex class object as parameter?

Tags: rest-api, apexrest, httppost

I am writing an Apex Rest Service with the `POST` Method. For that, I have written an apex class wrapper for the request. Like below.

```
global class RestRequestWrapper {
    global String eId;
    global Decimal salary;
    global String email;
    global Date joiningDate;
}
```

Below is the simplified version of my `doPost` method. Where I am passing an instance of `RestRequestWrapper` class a parameter.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/ExampleRestService/*')
global class ApexRestServiceExample {
    @HttpPost
    global static String doPost(RestRequestWrapper requestData) {
        System.debug(requestData);
        return 'success';
    }
}
```

When I am calling this API, from workbench with the below JSON body.

```
{
    "eId": "asasdasdasd",
    "salary": 122233,
    "email": "abc@xyz.com"
}
```

Returns this response.

```
[
    {
        "message": "Unexpected parameter encountered during deserialization: eId at [line:2, column:10]",
        "errorCode": "JSON_PARSER_ERROR"
    }
]
```

I don't run into any errors if I pass an empty JSON `{}`.

However, the JSON I am able to parse when fetched from the Request Body.
I am not getting what I am doing wrong here. What is the difference when it is fetched from `RestContext.request.requestBody.toString()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the name of the parameter, as you can have multiple parameters in any order. These look the following:

### JSON

```
{
    "requestData": 
        {
            "eId": "asasdasdasd",
            "salary": 122233,
            "email": "abc@xyz.com"
        }
}
```

### XML

```
<request>
    <requestData>
        <eId>asasdasdasd</iId>
        <salary>122233</salary>
        <email>abc@xyz.com</email>
    </requestData>
</request>
```

You can read more in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_methods.htm).

This is different than `RestContext.request.requestBody.toString()`, because the system provides automatic deserialization of the parameters for you. No need to call `Dom.Document.loadXml()` or `JSON.deserialize(payload)`, etc. The system automatically compensates for both XML and JSON by way of `Content-Type` provided by the API caller. The only downside is that you lose some control over the acceptable formats.